# Can I use identifiers in CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I want to apply some different styles to HTML elements giving them custom classes for which I will write different CSS style rules.

I'd like to do like:

```
<p class="padding-top-15">
```

And then have CSS rules where *`top`* and *`15`* are just identifiers.

For example I'd like my CSS to be like:

```
.padding-$identifier1-$identifier2 {
    padding-$identifier1: $identifier2 px;
}
```

Is this even possible with CSS3?

Comment: You may be able to achieve something like this with [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Comment: If so, could you offer an exlanation?

Comment: I'm going to take back what I've said. I've been playing with SASS and haven't been able to accomplish anything close to your question. Is there a reason you cannot just define `.padding-top-15`?

Comment: Because what if I want different size or even something different than top, like bottom or left

Comment: I think regardless of what you use you're still going to have to define each variable and identifier. You could separate everything into say `.padded { padding: 5px; } .padded-top { padding-top: 10px !important }` and then `<p class="padded padded-top">`

Comment: Not possible with CSS and even with pre-processors (like SASS or Less) you would need to give a fixed list of direction, size values and generate as many classes through loops. There is no real *dynamic* way of doing this. Also, as Jukka has already mentioned please do not name classes like this.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. There is nothing even remotely like that in CSS.

Try asking a new question where you explain what you wish to accomplish, instead of presenting an invented syntax to solve an unspecified problem. Note that if it occurred to you use a class name like `padding-top-15`, you have probably misunderstood some basic ideas of CSS. Think how confusing things will be if you later decide to change the top padding of that class to a top margin of 10px.